# Heroku system cannot find path specified

Tags: heroku

I'm doing the tutorial on Heroku Dev Center (found here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-scala#introduction). I got through all the steps leading up to running my app locally (as far as I can tell the app is deployed properly and I have installed the app dependencies), but when I run the command 'heroku local web -f Procfile.windows' it gives me back an error on web.1 saying "the system cannot find the path specified"... I double checked that web.1 is up using 'heroku ps' command.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be related to the JDK version. I was trying to use JDK 10.0.1 and encountered the same problem. When I changed to point to JDK 1.8.0_121 which (I think) Heroku installed, I was able to continue.

Answer (score 0):

The file specified at the *Procfile.windows* is not available, yet.

```
web: target\universal\stage\bin\play-getting-started.bat
```

To solve this, run:

```
sbt compile stage
```

in the root of the project directory to produce the required files.